# Laravel : create a helper or a model method to fetch data, which one is the best practice?

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, helper

I'd like to have some advice about that.

I have to run a query that returns a list of items from an alternative database of the web app. This list of items will go inside of a form which will be inserted on the database of the web app, so the list itself won't be modified.

Now here comes my question: what should I do? What is the best practice? to create a helper to fetch that list and similar data that won't be modified? Or to create a generic model for that kind of requests?

Thanks!

Comment: A new `Service Provider` is probably best practice.  In Laravel 5 things are much more geared toward Service Providers, so if you ever want to upgrade, its probably the path of least resistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's touching a database, you're probably best doing it in a model. You can specify the connection a model should talk to so if you have multiple databases you can have certain models connect to your alternative database and collect data as needed. You might want to prefix those models with something like `Legacy` (if they represent legacy data, for example).

If the data isn't going to change you might also consider using Eloquent's `remember()` method or otherwise caching the data so that it won't need to perform the query multiple times for the same data.

Comment: Finally that was the right (and best) solution. Just calling the model whenever needed does the work. `remember()` method is a good thing to know!